# Botpress native NLU languages supported

Tags: nlp, bots, chatbot

Is there a list of languages supported by Botpress **Native** NLP? Is Czech languages supported by default? Or only by using third party as Watson?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you were using early Botpress 11. In those versions, botpress was using [fasttext](https://fasttext.cc/) to train word vectors on the data you were providing with a basic whitespace tokenizer. Couple of pre-trained languages were offered but not Czech sadly.

In the newer version of Botpress (12.x), NLU structure seems to have drastically changed and more languages are supported but not Czech. The team said in their webinar that they would be deploying efforts to pre-train more languages and would require the community's help.