# How to add custom language in botpress?

Tags: javascript

Botpress version -11.5.0
how to add custom language to botpress? whether i need to write custom action for that are any other possibilities?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: See my other reply here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56962034/2244155